# Delete duplicate rows and add the deleted rows values to one that remain

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like :

```
id      |    name    |  profit |  cost  
---------------------------------------
1       |  aaa       | 4       | 2 
2       |  aaa       | 4       | 3 
3       |  aaa       | 4       | 2 
4       |  bbb       | 4       | 1
```

I want to delete from this table duplicate rows (according the name)
but before do the delete add the value of the deleted rows to the remain row

so in this case I want that the table after run queries look like :

```
id      |    name    |  profit |  cost  
---------------------------------------
1       |  aaa       | 12      | 7 
4       |  bbb       | 4       | 1
```

Is it possible to do it in mysql, without create another table and copy the data, because this is a big table (1 million rows but increase every day) ?

Comment: How big is 'very big'? Does it need to happen in one transaction? Is it a live system?

Comment: Do you really have the same ID  = 1 ?

Comment: don't you have any primary key on the table?

Comment: sory about the id, i fix it, its primary

Comment: Does the end result have to be the lowest ID for the set of records, or could it be a new record (e.g., `5 | aaa | 12 | 7`)

Comment: its can be new record

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b29c30/1)

First update rows with `min(id)` for each `NAME`

```
UPDATE T a JOIN 
(
  SELECT min(ID) as minID,name,SUM(profit) as SP,SUM(cost) as SC 
  FROM T GROUP BY name
) b 
 ON a.id = b.minID 
 SET a.profit = b.sp,a.cost=b.sc;
```

And then delete rows except only those rows with `min(id)` for each `NAME`

```
DELETE T
FROM T
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT min(ID) minid ,name FROM T GROUP BY name
) b  
ON t.id = b.minid
WHERE b.minid is NULL
```

Comment: This is the same as creating another table. The only difference is that it will be an invisible temp table. Its also slower because you are doing it twice.